# How to get the URL from QuerySet in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

```py
# Need:
some_method(SomeModel.objects.filter(some_field='some_value'))
# returns '?some_field__exact=some_value' — as is on admin pages changelists
```

Is there such a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not. You're mixing 2 differents things, Models and HTTP requests. So my guess is your question is actually "can I build an API to get data from my datastore just like using Models".

The answer to this new question is yes, you can look at http://www.django-rest-framework.org which provides a clean way to build such API.